# Jargon: von der Zucht ausgeschlossene Tiere

Tags: single-word-request

Gibt es im Tierzuchtjargon (insbesondere für die Hundezucht) ein *abfälliges*, möglicherweise *derbes* Wort für Tiere, die aufgrund eines genetischen Defekts von der weiteren Zucht ausgeschlossen sind?

Comment: Oh, ja: Hund. :)

Answer (score 0):

Umgekehrt wird eher ein Schuh draus: Tiere werden explizit für die Zucht ausgewählt ([gekört](https://www.dwds.de/wb/wdg/k%C3%B6ren), Substantiv für die positive Auswahl ist *die Körung*) und die Zucht mit anderen Tieren ist unerwünscht bzw. verboten; diese werden also als *zuchtuntauglich* eingestuft. Je nach Tierart kann man dafür ggf. verschiedene, spezifische, abfällige Wörter nutzen oder wählen wie bspw. bei Hunden "Straßenköter" (auch wenn diese Worte nicht unbedingt auf einen Gendefekt im engeren Sinne schließen lassen oder diesen gar implizieren, sondern nur, dass diese Tiere nicht den Zuchtzielen des entsprechenden Verbandes entsprechen).

Answer (score -2):

sehr abfällig: Bastard

abfällig: Mischling

Comment: Diese Begriffe meinen etwas anderes, nämlich die (oft unerwünschte) Vermischung von mehreren Arten, Tierrassen o. ä. Mischlinge können genetische Defekte haben, und sie können von der Zucht ausgeschlossen sein, aber die Begriffe haben nicht die Bedeutung, nach der gefragt war.